# pure function reading the state variables

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, blockchain

I am using **REMIX IDE** and on running the below code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.6;


contract enum1{
    enum FreshJuice{small,medium,large}
    FreshJuice choice;
    FreshJuice constant defaultChoice=FreshJuice.medium;

    function setLarge() public{
        choice=FreshJuice.large;
    }

    function setSmall() public{
        choice=FreshJuice.small;
    }

    function getChoice() public view returns(FreshJuice){
        return choice;
    }

    function getDefault() public view returns(uint){
        return uint(defaultChoice);
    }
}
```

I am getting this warning

```
Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure
  --> contracts/enumerator.sol:23:5:
   |
23 |     function getDefault() public view returns(uint){
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

But after changing **view** to **pure** in line 23, it doesn't give warning.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.6;


contract enum1{
    enum FreshJuice{small,medium,large}
    FreshJuice choice;
    FreshJuice constant defaultChoice=FreshJuice.medium;

    function setLarge() public{
        choice=FreshJuice.large;
    }

    function setSmall() public{
        choice=FreshJuice.small;
    }

    function getChoice() public view returns(FreshJuice){
        return choice;
    }

    function getDefault() public pure returns(uint){
        return uint(defaultChoice);
    }
}
```

Also how a pure function can read state variable.

Answer (score 1):

`Constants` arent stored in the contracts storage, they actually are inlined in the code, so you are indeed not reading from storage. See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#constant-and-immutable-state-variables